# Compile Two Class in Same Package

Tags: java, inheritance, package

Right now i am preparing myself for OCJP/SCJP exam. and i am doing my all programs through

the command line. I just discover one problem.

I have two classes Class1 And Class2. Both are in pack1.

```
package pack1;

public class Class1
{
        int var1 = 1;
        private int var2 = 2;
        public int var3 = 3;
        protected int var4 = 4;
}
```

I can compile this class from pack1 direcory.

Second Class

```
package pack1;
public class Class2 extends Class1
{
        public void accessVars()
        {

                System.out.println(var1);
                System.out.println(var2);
                System.out.println(var3);
                System.out.println(var4);
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                Class2 c = new Class2();
                c.accessVars();
        }
}
```

i can not compile this class from pack1 directory. i am getting "Can not find Symbol Error for Class1" but i can compile it from outside by importing pack1.Class1;

I know why this is Happening but i checked in NetBeans they can compile class Without Importing. How ? What should i do for compiling it fro pack1 directory.

Thanks,
Kshitij

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access `private` variables outside the class. Change them to public or protectd if you want them to be accessible in `Class2`

do as follows

```
javac pack1/Class1.java
javac pack1/Class2.java
```

In short,

- If you are compiling packaged java files, then compile from the directory from where package structure starts. e.g. in your case `javac pack1.Class1.java`
- When trying to launch those, use fully qualified class names e.g. `java pack1.Class2`

You can read this good tutorial on [how to compile and launch java programs in package structure](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/)

Comment: Working. Can you explain it in two or Three lines.

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly and added some reference links

Comment: Please remove above code class1 and Class2 code. i already know differences between private, public, protected and default. My error concerned to just compilation. that you solved it and explain it. Please remove it after i will accept your answer.

Comment: done as per your suggestion :). Read the link , it will help understand your concepts regarding compileation and launching programs

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is here in `Class2`:

```
System.out.println(var2);
```

`var2` is private in `Class1`, there's no way it can be seen by `Class2`

Answer (score 0):

To compile-

```
javac pack1\Class1.java 
javac pack1\Class2.java
```

To run-

```
java pack.Class2
```

Also as others mentioned, you cannot access a private member from another class. You can give getters for those members. Getters are public.

e.g. in Class1-

```
public int getVar2(){
    return this.var2;
}
```

Now from Class2, you can do-

```
System.out.println(c.getVar2());
```